# Can any experts here figure out how to get Mavericks' Dock.app working on Yosemite?

Tags: dock, macos

So one of the deal breakers that was preventing me from upgrading to OS X 10.10 is how ugly the dock looked (to me).

Since I had success getting some of the Yosemite's apps up and running on Mavericks (Yosemite's terminal for example, it supports scrolling with trackpad for some cli programs where you normally have to scroll with C-n, C-p or directional keys), naturally I tried the opposite, i.e. running Mavericks' Dock.app on Yosemite. Surprisingly, it worked! At least, partially. Functionality-wise, it works just fine, but on the looks it is missing the background image of the Mavericks' Dock.app.

Can someone more knowledgeable figure out a way to make this work 100%? As far as I know I'm not the only person wishing for this to work so if you can figure this out, you're doing us, a portion of the Mac community a big favor!

Answer (score 1):

There's an app online called cDocks should sort u out

> cDock will unleash your Dock! It's a small program to customize your
>   dock on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and 10.10 (Yosemite). There are several
>   dock styles included and users can also create their own custom docks.
>   What's New
>
> Version 6.0.6:
>
> ```
> Bug fix 'helpers folder not installing'
> Miscellaneous bug fixes
> Bug fix 'Custom dock not working properly'
> Bug fix 'junktest.txt created on desktop when updating'
> Miscellaneous bug fixes
> UI adjustments
> Bug fix 'themes not loading'
> Miscellaneous bug fixes
> Updated donors in credits
> UI redesign
> more...
> ```
>
> Requirements
>
> ```
> Intel
> OS X 10.9 or later
> ```

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/51149/cdock

Answer (score 1):

I agree cDock is the way to go. I too hated the Yosemite Dock and easily got it with cDock, it is easy to get back your old dock and get coloured docks, app spacers and more. It is a very useful app and I believe will do the trick. You can also get the 10.8 dock as well as 10.9. I think this is the best thing to use. Here are some screenshots. Hope it works out! BC9973 [image: Cdock1]

[image: Cdock2]

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with the Dock being half-transparent, you can copy the resources form the Mavericks Dock.app (show package contents) and copy all files to Yosemite Dock.app.

Comment: I've edited your answer to remove the "question part". Please use the "Ask Question" link on top to ask new questions.

Comment: Do you happen to have a screenshot of what the end result looks like? What does "half-transparent" mean?